# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n = +\infty$ given $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a < 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Can somebody check if my proof is correct, the last part is the only one that I am a bit unsure of.

Given that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a < 0$, we choose $\epsilon = -\frac{a}{2} > 0$. By the definition of a limit, there exists an $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n > N_1$, we have

$$
|a_n - a| < \epsilon.
$$

This implies

$$
a - \epsilon < a_n < a + \epsilon,
$$

which simplifies to

$$
a_n < a + \left(-\frac{a}{2}\right) = \frac{a}{2},
$$

given that $a < 0$.

Now, let $C$ be any real number. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = -\infty$, there exists an $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N_2$,

$$
b_n < \frac{2C}{a}.
$$

Define $N_3 = \max(N_1, N_2)$. For all $n > N_3$, it follows that

$$
a_n b_n > \left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{2C}{a}\right) = C.
$$

Hence, we have proved that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n = +\infty$.

Comment: By the "last part", am I right in guessing that it's the multiplication of inequalities involving negative numbers? If it helps, view them as $-a_n > -\frac{a}{2}$ and $-b_n > -\frac{2C}{a}$, where both sides of both inequalities are positive numbers. Multiplying these inequalities of positive numbers together yields $a_n b_n > C$, as required.

Comment: Okay but should I then explicitly state that C>0 to ensure that  2C/a is negative, or is it okay to leave it as an arbitrary real number?

Comment: Good point: yes you should. You lose no generality by making this assumption.

Comment: From $a_n < a/2 < 0$ and $b_n < 2C/a$, 

$$a_nb_n > a_n\cdot\frac {2C}a \underset{(*)}> \frac a2 \cdot \frac{2C}a = C$$

The $(*)$ inequality assumes $2C/a <0$ and $C>0$, so mentioning that would be better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will mention it in my proof!

Comment: To avoid negative sign since $a_n b_n =(-a_n)(-b_n)=c_n d_n$ we can also prove the equivalent for $c_n\to c>0$ and $d_n \to \infty$.